# How to add pandas DataFrame columns with misaligned indexes?

Tags: python, indexing, sum, dataframe

How do I get C from A and B?

```
Index         A     B     C
5/7/2014      1           1
5/8/2014      2           2
5/9/2014      0     1     1
5/10/2014     4     2     6
5/11/2014     3     1     4
5/12/2014     4     2     6
```

The index consists of Datetime objects.  Otherwise, I think I could just fillna(0.0) and sum them.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal example that creates your object?

Comment: Creates which object?  The DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, right, it would spare the time to imitate your dataframe.